# How to convert byte string with non-printable chars to hexadecimal in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hex, byte

I have an ANSI string `Ď–ór˙rXüď\ő‡íQl7` and I need to convert it to hexadecimal like this: 
`06cf96f30a7258fcef5cf587ed51156c37` (converted with XVI32).

The problem is that Python cannot encode all characters correctly (some of them are incorrectly displayed even here, on Stack Overflow) so I have to deal with them with a byte string.

So the above string is in bytes this: `b'\x06\xcf\x96\xf3\nr\x83\xffrX\xfc\xef\\\xf5\x87\xedQ\x15l7'`

And that's what I need to convert to hexadecimal.

So far I tried binascii with no success, I've tried this:

```
h = ""
for i in b'\x06\xcf\x96\xf3\nr\x83\xffrX\xfc\xef\\\xf5\x87\xedQ\x15l7':
    h += hex(i)
print(h)
```

It prints:

`0x60xcf0x960xf30xa0x720x830xff0x720x580xfc0xef0x5c0xf50x870xed0x510x150x6c0x37`

Okay. It looks like I'm getting somewhere... but what's up with the `0x` thing?

When I remove 0x from the string like this:

```
h.replace("0x", "")
```

I get `6cf96f3a7283ff7258fcef5cf587ed51156c37` which looks like it's correct.

But sometimes the byte string has a `0` next to a `x` and it gets removed from the string resulting in a incorrect hexadecimal string. (the string above is missing the 0 at the beginning).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running python 3.5+, `bytes` type has an new [`bytes.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method that returns string representation.

```
>>> h = b'\x06\xcf\x96\xf3\nr\x83\xffrX\xfc\xef\\\xf5\x87\xedQ\x15l7'
b'\x06\xcf\x96\xf3\nr\x83\xffrX\xfc\xef\\\xf5\x87\xedQ\x15l7'
>>> h.hex()
'06cf96f30a7283ff7258fcef5cf587ed51156c37'
```

Otherwise you can use [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) to do the same thing

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(h).decode('utf8')
'06cf96f30a7283ff7258fcef5cf587ed51156c37'
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. That’s great, thanks!

Comment: and in reverse: `h = bytes.fromhex('06cf96f30a7283ff7258fcef5cf587ed51156c37')`.

Comment: On Python 2, you could use `h.encode('hex')`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) converts *“an integer number to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with ‘0x’*.” So when using `hex()` you always get a `0x` prefix. You will always have to remove that if you want to concatenate multiple hex representations.

> But sometimes the byte string has a `0` next to a `x` and it gets removed from the string resulting in a incorrect hexadecimal string. (the string above is missing the `0` at the beginning).

That does not make any sense. `x` is not a valid hexadecimal character, so in your solution it can *only* be generated by the `hex()` call. And that, as said above, will always create a `0x`. So the sequence `0x` can *never* appear in a different way in your resulting string, so replacing `0x` by nothing should work just fine.

The actual problem in your solution is that `hex()` does not enforce a two-digit result, as simply shown by this example:

```
>>> hex(10)
'0xa'
>>> hex(2)
'0x2'
```

So in your case, since the string starts with `b\x06` which represents the number `6`, `hex(6)` only returns `0x6`, so you only get a single digit here which is the real cause of your problem.

---

What you can do is use format strings to perform the conversion to hexadecimal. That way you can both leave out the prefix and enforce a length of two digits. You can then use `str.join` to combine it all into a single hexadecimal string:

```
>>> value = b'\x06\xcf\x96\xf3\nr\x83\xffrX\xfc\xef\\\xf5\x87\xedQ\x15l7'
>>> ''.join(['{:02x}'.format(x) for x in value])
'06cf96f30a7283ff7258fcef5cf587ed51156c37'
```

This solution does not only work with a bytes string but with really anything that can be formatted as a hexadecimal string (e.g. an integer list):

```
>>> value = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> ''.join(['{:02x}'.format(x) for x in value])
'01020304'
```